# How to only affect one item in a for-loop list?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to manipulate items in a list that is generated with a for-loop (`ngFor`). But at the moment it changes all my items if I want to change one. How can I only dress it to one item, so one item changes in color and icon?

html

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let friend of loadedFriends; let i = index">


          <ion-label text-wrap>
                  <h2 class="title">Friend</h2>
                  <p class="status"> Status</p> 
                </ion-label>
                <ion-buttons>
                    <ion-button size="large" (click)="removeFriend(i)" (click)="onAdd(i)" slot="icon-only">
                    <ion-icon [color]="added ? 'primary' : 'light'" [name]="added ? 'add-circle-outline' : 'checkmark-circle-outline'"></ion-icon>
                  </ion-button>
                </ion-buttons>
              </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

ts

```
  public added: boolean = true;

...

onAdd(id: number): void {
  this.added = !this.added;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must keep track of the `added` status for each item in your loop.

Here's a way to do so:

```js
loadedFriendsMap: { [k: string]: boolean } = {};

/* ... */

onAdd (friendId) {
 this.loadedFriendsMap[friendId] = true;
}

removeFriend (friendId) {
 this.loadedFriendsMap[friendId] = false;
}

/* ... */
```

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let friend of loadedFriends; let i = index">
        <ion-label text-wrap>
            <h2 class="title">Friend</h2>
            <p class="status"> Status</p> 
        </ion-label>

        <ion-buttons>
            <ion-button size="large" (click)="removeFriend(i)" (click)="onAdd(i)" slot="icon-only">
            <ion-icon [color]="loadedFriendsMap[i] ? 'primary' : 'light'" [name]="loadedFriendsMap[i] ? 'add-circle-outline' : 'checkmark-circle-outline'"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-item>
<ion-list>
```

Comment: `loadedFriendsMap: { [k: id]: boolean } = {};`  this gives me an error: That `id` wasn't found and that an index signature parameters type has to be of type `string` or type `number`

Comment: @ColinRagnarök sorry! It should've been `string`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It works now for adding it, so that the icon changes to the checkmark, but I can't change it back anymore to the plus icon with primary color

Comment: I changed it to: `onAdd (friendId) {
    this.loadedFriendsMap[friendId] = !this.loadedFriendsMap[friendId];
   }` now I can change it back

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable added is kind of global and not tied to any object. One of the other way to fix this is, add this variable/attribute to all objects.

```
for(i = 0; i < loadedFriends.length; i++){
    loadedFriends[i].added = false;
}
```

And the onAdd method will look like below. and in HTML the onAdd method will be passed like this: onAdd(friend) instead of onAdd(i).

```
onAdd(friendObj): void {
    friendObj.added = !friendObj.added;
}
```

I feel this approach is better as the attribute is tied to the object itself which gives you more control than maintaining a separate array/hash-map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the added index and store it in a variable if you want to select only one a time.

eg.

Html

```
      <ion-label text-wrap>
              <h2 class="title">Friend</h2>
              <p class="status"> Status</p> 
            </ion-label>
            <ion-buttons>
                <ion-button size="large" (click)="removeFriend(i)" (click)="onAdd(i)" slot="icon-only">
                <ion-icon [color]="(addedIndex === i)  ? 'primary' : 'light'" [name]="(addedIndex === i) ? 'add-circle-outline' : 'checkmark-circle-outline'"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

ts

```
public addedIndex: boolean = true;

...

onAdd(id: number): void {
  this.addedIndex = id;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach! But, by using this, you are limited to only one added friend, right?

Comment: @AndreiGătej yes,  i have mentioned it in my answer and his requirement is also the same.